# JavaScript or CSS: How can I make a transition of one element to another?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on my custom home page and I'd like to make a transition of one element to another.

Here's my HTML code:

```
                <div id="index-features">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <h5 id="feature-1" class="feature-title">Instant access</h5>
                            <span id="feature-1-description" class="feature-description">After purchasing a style, there will be no waiting. Your account will be directly promoted in the "Customers" group and you will unlock access to all the features of the forum.</span>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <h5 id="feature-2" class="feature-title">Compatibility with all browsers</h5>
                            <span id="feature-2-description" class="feature-description">The styles are tested on all browsers to analyze any bugs and if we find, we correct them.</span>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <h5 id="feature-3" class="feature-title">Modern techniques</h5>
                            <span id="feature-3-description" class="feature-description">We use modern techniques (CSS3 gradients, etc.) to stand out from others.</span>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <h5 id="feature-4" class="feature-title">Compatibility with the default XenForo products</h5>
                            <span id="feature-4-description" class="feature-description">The styles are worked not only for the forum software, but also for the default XenForo products (Media Gallery and Resource Manager).</span>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <h5 id="feature-5" class="feature-title">Optional copyright removal</h5>
                            <span id="feature-5-description" class="feature-description">By paying more for a style, you can remove the copyright ("Style by XenDesignFocus") of the style.</span>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <h5 id="feature-6" class="feature-title">Compatibility with any resolution</h5>
                            <span id="feature-6-description" class="feature-description">The styles are designed to be compatible on any resolution. They are responsive, so they will fit on tablet and mobile.</span>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <h5 id="feature-7" class="feature-title">High quality support</h5>
                            <span id="feature-7-description" class="feature-description">If you need help about a purchased style here, ask in the <a href="#" target="_blank" style="border-bottom: 2px solid;">support forum</a> so that we can fix your problem very quickly.</span>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <h5 id="feature-8" class="feature-title">Custom framework</h5>
                            <span id="feature-8-description" class="feature-description">All styles are based on a custom framework for features such as the ability to change the logo image with a HTML logo text, make the appearance of the avatars in rounded, put a custom node icon for each forum, etc.</span>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <h5 id="feature-9" class="feature-title">Extra features</h5>
                            <span id="feature-9-description" class="feature-description">In addition to the custom framework, some styles have custom features such as for example the possibility to enable the fixed header option, etc.</span>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <h5 id="feature-10" class="feature-title">Test title</h5>
                            <span id="feature-10-description" class="feature-description">Test</span>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

CSS:

```
#index-features
{
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}

#index-features li
{
    border-bottom: #CCCCCC 1px solid;
    margin: 0 -20px 20px -20px;
    padding: 0 20px; 0 20px;
}

#index-features ul:last-child li:last-child
{
    border-bottom: none;
}

.feature-title
{
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.feature-title:before
{
    content: "";
    float: left;
    background: url("../images/index-features-sprite.png") no-repeat;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

.feature-description
{
    display: block;
    margin: 0 0 20px 37px;
}

#feature-1:before
{
    background-position: 0 0;
}

#feature-2:before
{
    background-position: -32px 0;
}

#feature-3:before
{
    background-position: -64px 0;
}

#feature-4:before
{
    background-position: 0 -32px;
}

#feature-5:before
{
    background-position: -32px -32px;
}

#feature-6:before
{
    background-position: 0 -64px;
}

#feature-7:before
{
    background-position: -32px -64px;
}

#feature-8:before
{
    background-position: -64px -32px;
}

#feature-9:before
{
    background-position: -64px -64px;
}
```

As you can see, I've two ul tag and what I want is to do a transition of the first ul to the other ul: http://prntscr.com/7ftax4 and the second ul: http://prntscr.com/7ftba6

The idea would be that the first ul is displayed and after 10 seconds, second ul passes over the first ul.

How can I do it with JavaScript or CSS please?

Comment: transition timeout? Just an idea I got by quickly looking through your question :D

Comment: What about JQuery UI?  You can play with the different effects they've got to get the look and feel you'd like and just have timers to trigger on the schedule you'd like  https://jqueryui.com/show/

Comment: Yes, I would like that the first ul be replaced by the second having a transition and that it is infinite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a piece of jQuery which will successively add an active class over the `<ul>` elements. Then using CSS the `<ul>` elements can be hidden and shown when the `.active` class is applied

```js
$(function(){
  $('#index-features ul').first().addClass('active');
  setInterval(loop,10000);
  
  function loop(){
    var $active=$('ul.active');
    var $next=$active.nextAll('ul').first();
    if($next.length===0)$next=$active.prevAll('ul').last();
    $active.removeClass('active')
    $next.addClass('active');
  }
});
```

```css
#index-features
{
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}

#index-features li
{
    border-bottom: #CCCCCC 1px solid;
    margin: 0 -20px 20px -20px;
    padding: 0 20px; 0 20px;
}

#index-features ul:last-child li:last-child
{
    border-bottom: none;
}

.feature-title
{
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.feature-title:before
{
    content: "";
    float: left;
    background: url("../images/index-features-sprite.png") no-repeat;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

.feature-description
{
    display: block;
    margin: 0 0 20px 37px;
}

#feature-1:before
{
    background-position: 0 0;
}

#feature-2:before
{
    background-position: -32px 0;
}

#feature-3:before
{
    background-position: -64px 0;
}

#feature-4:before
{
    background-position: 0 -32px;
}

#feature-5:before
{
    background-position: -32px -32px;
}

#feature-6:before
{
    background-position: 0 -64px;
}

#feature-7:before
{
    background-position: -32px -64px;
}

#feature-8:before
{
    background-position: -64px -32px;
}

#feature-9:before
{
    background-position: -64px -64px;
}

#index-features ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}
#index-features ul.active {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="index-features">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <h5 id="feature-1" class="feature-title">Instant access</h5>
                            <span id="feature-1-description" class="feature-description">After purchasing a style, there will be no waiting. Your account will be directly promoted in the "Customers" group and you will unlock access to all the features of the forum.</span>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <h5 id="feature-2" class="feature-title">Compatibility with all browsers</h5>
                            <span id="feature-2-description" class="feature-description">The styles are tested on all browsers to analyze any bugs and if we find, we correct them.</span>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <h5 id="feature-3" class="feature-title">Modern techniques</h5>
                            <span id="feature-3-description" class="feature-description">We use modern techniques (CSS3 gradients, etc.) to stand out from others.</span>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <h5 id="feature-4" class="feature-title">Compatibility with the default XenForo products</h5>
                            <span id="feature-4-description" class="feature-description">The styles are worked not only for the forum software, but also for the default XenForo products (Media Gallery and Resource Manager).</span>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <h5 id="feature-5" class="feature-title">Optional copyright removal</h5>
                            <span id="feature-5-description" class="feature-description">By paying more for a style, you can remove the copyright ("Style by XenDesignFocus") of the style.</span>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <h5 id="feature-6" class="feature-title">Compatibility with any resolution</h5>
                            <span id="feature-6-description" class="feature-description">The styles are designed to be compatible on any resolution. They are responsive, so they will fit on tablet and mobile.</span>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <h5 id="feature-7" class="feature-title">High quality support</h5>
                            <span id="feature-7-description" class="feature-description">If you need help about a purchased style here, ask in the <a href="#" target="_blank" style="border-bottom: 2px solid;">support forum</a> so that we can fix your problem very quickly.</span>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <h5 id="feature-8" class="feature-title">Custom framework</h5>
                            <span id="feature-8-description" class="feature-description">All styles are based on a custom framework for features such as the ability to change the logo image with a HTML logo text, make the appearance of the avatars in rounded, put a custom node icon for each forum, etc.</span>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <h5 id="feature-9" class="feature-title">Extra features</h5>
                            <span id="feature-9-description" class="feature-description">In addition to the custom framework, some styles have custom features such as for example the possibility to enable the fixed header option, etc.</span>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <h5 id="feature-10" class="feature-title">Test title</h5>
                            <span id="feature-10-description" class="feature-description">Test</span>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                </div>
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks, but why ul disappears after two ul are displayed? I'd like it be infinite please.

Comment: My mistake. I have added the functionality

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with pure CSS, but you need animation and animation delay. I have made a fiddle where one `div` will be covered by another `div` after 10 seconds so be patient: http://jsfiddle.net/Lcek5s21/

```
#number1, #number2 {
        height:100px;
        width: 100px;
    }
#number1 {
        background-color:red;
    }
#number2 {
        background-color:green;
        -webkit-animation: mymove 3s infinite;/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
        -webkit-animation-delay: 10s;/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
        animation: mymove 3s infinite;
        animation-delay: 10s;
        position:relative;
        opacity:0;
    }
@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
        0% {
            top: 0px;
            opacity: 0;
        }
        100% {
            top: -100px;
            opacity: 1;
        }
    }
/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes mymove {
        0% {
            top: 0px;
            opacity: 0;
        }
    100% {
        top: -100px;
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```